# Power BI - count number of rows based on filter in one row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to count rows based on filter in row called `flag`.
I want to count only rows where flag is 1 or 2 and put that in variable since I'll need it for further calculation.

Sample data:

[image]

I have something like this so far but it's not working:

```
var average = CALCULATE(COUNTA(FILTER(table;[flag] = 1 && [flag] = 2)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with:

```
COUNTROWS(FILTER(table;[flag] == 1 || [flag] == 2))
```

thank you @Ivo for the tip about ||. I didn't manage to make it work with CALCULATE.

Answer (score 1):

In the COUNTA function, you first must write the column you want to count. After, you apply the filter to the CALCULATE function (you don’t need the filter statement here):

```
var average = CALCULATE(COUNTA(table;[flag]); table[flag] = 1 && table[flag] = 2)
```

Comment: Problem is && its implying both conditions have to be met. How do I put OR there?

Comment: Use || instead of &&